# Magento exclude products from Checkout with PayPal

Tags: magento, paypal

I need to exclude some products from Checkout with PayPal on PRODUCT DETAIL Page. I have a custom attribute "paypal > yes/no".

Where do I fit the condition?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You would copy the file;

`app/design/frontend/base/default/template/paypal/express/shortcut.phtml`

Into your package/theme and modify it by wrapping the code in your conditional based on your Paypal attribute.